# Assembly: Dword to Hex conversion problem

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am new to reverse engineering, and working with IDA I saw that the `wstring` 'CPRE' has been converted in the `rdata` section as the following:

```
rdata:00417B30 ; const WCHAR Caption

rdata:00417B30 Caption         dd 500043h  
rdata:00417B34 dword_417B34    dd 450052h             
rdata:00417B38 word_417B38     dw 0                    
 
rdata:00417B3A                 align 4
```

Why? I mean, `43h` is the hex for 'C', `50h` for 'P' but why the 00 between?
Can someone help?

The code is 32bit and IDA idafreeware64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, those are wide strings, consisting of wide (16-bit) characters.

Those `dd` constants are 4-byte (32-bit). What the disassembly doesn't show you is that there are high-order 0 bytes in those constants:

`500043h` is really `00500043h`. It consists of the two characters `0050h` (P) and `0043h` (C).

The same applies for the other two letters. There is no `00h` between them, that's part of the first (lower-order) character in the literal.

---

This could be less confusingly written (while still keeping it as raw data, not parsed as a wstring):

```
rdata:00417B30 Caption         dw 0043h  
rdata:00417B32 word_417B32     dw 0050h   
rdata:00417B34 word_417B34     dw 0052h   
rdata:00417B36 word_417B36     dw 0045h             
rdata:00417B38 word_417B38     dw 0
```

where the `00`s could be dropped, but have been included to make clear the width.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I imagined that but the 00 missing at the beginning fooled me. Thank you againt